# need List search functionality in VFR Reader

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have implemented **Pdf reading library** from [this tutorial:](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/reading-displaying-pdf-documents/). It's based on **[VFR Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader)**.

Now I want to add **List search results** functionality. If you have some idea about **[FastPdfKit](https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit)** it's provided List search functionality.

I want same search functionality as attached image.

If any body had implemented same search functionality in VFR Reader than I will really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

[image: iPhone Screenshot showing search functionality]

Comment: Is there a particular issue your having whilst trying to implement or don't you have a clue where to start? You don't tell us exactly what you are after. It just seems like - "I want to implement this can someone do it for me." That is just my opinion. +1 for the links they are interesting.

Comment: @Popeye thanks for replay, i really have not clue where to start from, if you can give some clue what i have to do from now on? from where can i start it? its very help full to me, i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following method to find words from pdf.
It may help you.

```
-(BOOL)page:(CGPDFPageRef)inPage containsString:(NSString *)inSearchString;
{
[self setCurrentData:[NSMutableString string]];
CGPDFContentStreamRef contentStream = CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage(inPage);
CGPDFScannerRef scanner = CGPDFScannerCreate(contentStream, table, self);
bool ret = CGPDFScannerScan(scanner);
CGPDFScannerRelease(scanner);
CGPDFContentStreamRelease(contentStream);
 NSLog(@"%@",[currentData uppercaseString]);
 NSLog(@"%d",[[currentData uppercaseString]rangeOfString:[inSearchString uppercaseString]].location != NSNotFound);
return ([[currentData uppercaseString]rangeOfString:[inSearchString uppercaseString]].location != NSNotFound);
}
```