# Unable to read text from Pdf in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, cgpdfdocument, cgpdfscanner

I am trying to extract text for pdf document in my iOS application, I am using **CGPDFScanner**.. 
I used the reference from these links:

- [need List search functionality in VFR Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010176/need-list-search-functionality-in-vfr-reader)
- [Displaying and Searching PDF Content on iPhone](http://blog.random-ideas.net/?p=184)

The methods specified in the above two links work for some simple [(Programming in Objective-c)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321811909) type of pdf.. but when I try to extract text from pdf such as those in "[Head First](http://filepi.com/i/YnwcDwN)" series I get garbage value. Please suggest me some solution which will work for all types of pdf

Comment: @BradLarson why negative vote?

Comment: I didn't vote on your question, merely edited it to remove the link to a bootleg ebook.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PDFKitten, it can be CMap parsing issue in that. I have resolved this issue and found that searching is going well in almost every pdf.

Comment: If you using PDFKitten, it have many problems with PDF having ToUnicodeMapping. It's parsing of CMap is totally wrong. It throws away most of the mapping while parsing. If you can fix that you will be able to search in PDF properly as you will be availed with proper text.

Answer (score -1):

Try using http://fastpdfkit.com/ , this is one of the best pdf reader library that i have used.

Comment: I have seen fastpdfkit, but I can't use it because it does not make use of CGPDFDictionary, and I want to do by using it. I have also tried PDFKitten but this library also not able to scan pdf text properly. Do suggest some alternative way (code snippet) to this problem.

Comment: Hmmm, I didint faced this issue. Currently i dont have any alternative, but will let you know if i find any.